# How do I read in a csv file to sckkit-learn tree

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I am somewhat familiar with `R` and straight `python` but not `scikit-learn` or `numpy`.

I found the following code for the iris data set included in `scikit-learn` at http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html#tree

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn import tree
iris = load_iris()
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)
```

Rather than use iris that is part of `scikit-learn`, I want to load a csv file that is in the form:

```
A,B,C,D
5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2
4.9,3.0,1.4,0.2
4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2
4.6,3.1,1.5,0.2
.........
```

How do I load it, get it into `clf.fit(?,?)` and what do I need to use in place of `iris.target`?

Comment: You can load it with `data = np.genfromtext('filename.csv', delimiter=',', skip_header=1)`.  You would pass it to `clf.fit` like: `clf.fit(data, ___)` where you should fill in the blank with your `target`, but I'm not sure what that would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/). It implements something similar to the R dataframe. You need to convert the dataframe to a numpy array before using it with sklearn though (np.array(df))

Answer (score 0):

data.txt:

a,b,c,d 
5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2 
4.9,3.0,1.4,0.2
4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2
4.6,3.1,1.5,0.2

To load data you can use numpy.loadtxt:

```
    import numpy as np
    from sklearn import tree

    mydata=np.loadtxt('data.txt',dtype=np.object,delimiter=',')
    mydata=mydata[1:].astype(np.float) # Perform conversion (for quantitative features only)

    clf=tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()

    #According to sklearn documentation we should map all class marks to integers
    #Lets do it:
    translation_table={'mark1':1,'mark2':2,'mark3':3} #or {'setosa': 1, 'virginia' :2} etc.
    target_data=['mark1','mark2','mark1','mark3', ] #etc.
    int_target_data=map(lambda x: translation_table[x],target_data) # Perform mapping needed by sklearn classifiers
    clf.fit(mydata,int_target_data) # train your classifier
```